# Angularjs Directive -> child directive variables with transclusion

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm making a complex view with a parent directive, and some sub-directives nested in. I've run into a problem where it seems like variables aren't being passed through the layers of directives properly.

Here's the setup:

```
<header>
    <div expandable expand="functionFromHeader">
        <div votable show-vote="variableFromHeader">
            ...
            <!-- from votable template -->
            <vote>
                <!-- from vote template -->
                <div class="vote" ng-show="showVote">vote</div>
            </vote>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="contentGettingExpanded" ng-show="variableFromHeader">
        ...
    </div>
</header>
```

Both the **expandable** directive and the **votable** directive use transclusion.

The function from the header scope "functionFromHeader" toggles the variable "variableFromHeader".

The problem is the variable starts out false, but the votes show up anyway. (In the link function I inspected it an it is coming through as a string "variableFromHeader" rather than the value of the variable.

The content that is supposed to expand and collapse, starts collapsed as it should, but once it is expanded, it doesn't collapse. The content just flashes on the screen.

How do I properly pass the variables through the directives?

Comment: Could you make a fiddle/plunkr of the example? Or at least post the directive code? It's very hard to help without knowing how the scopes are setup in the directives and what functionFromHeader invocation works.

Comment: don't use a primitive, pass an object through instead. You are running into scope inheritance issue using a primitive

Comment: what do you mean a primitive? You mean passing a boolean through?

Comment: OMG I found the problem!! For some reason I don't understand at all... adding a transition effect (standard-transition {
  -webkit-transition:all linear 0.5s;
  -moz-transition:all linear 0.5s;
  -o-transition:all linear 0.5s;
  transition:all linear 0.5s;
  display:block !important;
}) with css (taken from the angular-animate documentation) completely messes up the angular scopes.